# Cannot remove youtube masthead since recent change

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, ubuntu-16.04

I dislike the "masthead" at the top of youtube (the part containing the search bar) because you can't scroll it off the screen.

I was trying to remove it as below, but it doesn't work. It used to work, but youtube changed their page a few days ago. Their current page is very complicated. I've tried it with the different @run-at possibilities: document-end, document-start, document-idle. It always shows the "bad child" popup.

It can be removed in Firefox by using the element inspector and deleting the node.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YouTube
// @namespace   X
// @include     https://www.youtube.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-idle
// ==/UserScript==

function rem(id) {
    var child = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!child) { alert("bad child: " + id); return; }
    var parent = child.parentElement;
    if (!parent) { alert("bad parent: " + id); return; }
    parent.removeChild(child);
}

rem("masthead-container");
```

Comment: Uhm, simply add `@grant GM_addStyle` and invoke it with #masthead-container.ytd-app { position: static !important; } #page-manager.ytd-app { margin-top: 0 !important; }

Comment: @wOxxOm, Uhm, did you try it yourself? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah, of course, it works for me.

Comment: The script is correct for the main page. On video pages sometimes another element with fixed position is added so simply add `, #masthead-positioner` before the first `{`.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Oh my god! I'm so sorry. I was expecting it to disappear, but obviously the code simply makes it scrollable. I'm an idiot! Anyway, great idea. Works perfectly, of course. Sorry again. Sheesh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with timeouts, to retry it until it works.

`if (!child) { alert("bad child: " + id); return; }`

turn this ^ into

`if (!child) { console.log("bad child: " + id); setTimeout(rem, 3000, "masthead-container"); return; }`

This might add up to a bit of recursive calls but it will eventually work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers from the two people who helped me, here are two solutions:

From Pinkie Pie:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YouTube
// @namespace   X
// @include     https://www.youtube.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-end
// ==/UserScript==

function remove_masthead() {
    var child = document.getElementById("masthead-container");
    if (child) {
        child.parentElement.removeChild(child);
        setTimeout(scroll, 1000, 0, 80);
    }
    else
        setTimeout(remove_masthead, 1000);
}

remove_masthead();
```

From wOxxOm:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YouTube
// @namespace   X
// @include     https://www.youtube.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @run-at      document-end
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle("#masthead-container.ytd-app { position: static !important; } #page-manager.ytd-app { margin-top: 0 !important; }")
setTimeout(scroll, 3000, 0, 80);
```